# how to use the recognized text with Google Assistant's hotword.py code

Tags: extract, google-assistant-sdk

How do I get the spoken text from the hotword.py code & do my own actions on the recognised text rather than Google going off and reacting to the text?

I've installed GA on the Pi3 & after some initial issues with usb mic/analogue audio settings and certain Python files missing this got me going:
[When installing Google Assistant, I an error "...googlesamples.assistant' is a package and cannot be directly executed..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091251/when-installing-google-assistant-i-an-error-googlesamples-assistant-is-a-p)
I then followed the Google Next steps : https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample and created a new project "myga/" with a hotword.py file that contains:

```
def process_event(event):
"""Pretty prints events.

Prints all events that occur with two spaces between each new
conversation and a single space between turns of a conversation.

Args:
    event(event.Event): The current event to process.
"""
if event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
    print()
    #GPIO.output(25,True)           see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219740/how-can-i-get-an-led-to-light-on-google-assistant-listening

if event.type == EventType.ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
    print("got some work to do here with the phrase or text spoken!")

print(event)

if (event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED and
        event.args and not event.args['with_follow_on_turn']):
    print()
    #GPIO.output(25,False)          or also see https://blog.arevindh.com/2017/05/20/voice-activated-google-assistant-on-raspberry-pi-with-visual-feedback/
```

I'd like code to react to the ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED event I think and at either do my own action by matching simple requests or if the phrase is not in my list then let Google handle it.  How do I do that?

Eventually I'd be asking "OK Google, turn BBC1 on" or "OK Google, play my playlist" or "OK Google, show traffic" and hotword.py would run other applications to do those tasks.

Thanks, Steve

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/library/python/ it probably involves calling stop_conversation() to cease further processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation here for all available methods -
 https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/library/python/

You can use the `stop_conversation()` method to stop Google Assistant handling that request and act on your own.

Here's what you need to do at a high level -

1. Build your own dictionary of commands that you'd like to handle -
   "turn BBC1 on", "play my playlist" etc.
2. On `EventType.ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED` event check if the
   recognized command exists in your dictionary.
3. If the recognized command exists in your dictionary call the `assistant.stop_conversation()` method and handle the command on your own. If not do nothing (let google handle it)

pseudo code -

```
local_commands  = ['turnBBCOn', 'playLocalPlaylist']

function turnBBCOn() :
#handle locally


function playLocalPlaylist() :
#handle locally


def process_event(event):

    if event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
        print()

    if event.type == EventType.ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
        print(event.args['text'])
        if event.args['text'] in local_commands:
            assistant.stop_conversation()
            if(event.args['text']='turn BBC1 on')
                turnBBCOn()
            elif(event.args['text']='play my playlist')
                playLocalPlaylist()

    if (event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED and
        event.args and not event.args['with_follow_on_turn']):
        print()
```

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I was missing the events.args[] information to get me started.

Comment: @Steve - just curious, I'm doing something similar, do you have your code somewhere in GitHub? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have recently integrated google assistant SDK with Raspberry Pi 3. I have taken reference from below git repository and created action.py and actionbase.py classes can handle my custom command. I found it very clean and flexible way to create your own custom commands.

You can register your custom command in action.py file like below

```
actor = actionbase.Actor()

actor.add_keyword(
    _('ip address'), SpeakShellCommandOutput(
        say, "ip -4 route get 1 | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f8",
        _('I do not have an ip address assigned to me.')))

return actor
```

## action.py

Write your custom code in action.py

```
"""Speaks out the output of a shell command."""

def __init__(self, say, shell_command, failure_text):
    self.say = say
    self.shell_command = shell_command
    self.failure_text = failure_text

def run(self, voice_command):
    output = subprocess.check_output(self.shell_command, shell=True).strip()
    if output:
        self.say(output.decode('utf-8'))
    elif self.failure_text:
        self.say(self.failure_text)
```

You can full source code here. https://github.com/aycgit/google-assistant-hotword

Comment: Please don't post "link-only" answers. Additional to the link you should summarize the essence and post it here!

Answer (score 0):

The text is contained within the event arguments. By calling event.args you can make use of the text. Here is an example.

https://github.com/shivasiddharth/GassistPi/blob/master/src/main.py